# Creating a label in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to set a label on Azure Devops task, but **not** via the built-in label option as you can see on the attached photo.

How can I do it?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tf.exe` command is available on the build agent. Simply use a command-line script in your pipeline with the appropriate [tf command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/label-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=azure-devops).

```
- task: Cmdline@2
  inputs:
    script: 'tf label goodbuild docs /recursive'
```